# How to hide a physical nic card from showing ip in DNS table?

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v

I have a Hyper-V Server running Windows Server 2008R2 which has four physical nics. Is there a way that I can hide three of these nics? The reason is they have static IPs and are showing in the local DNS table with same name.

Answer (score 2):

Open the TCP/IP properties of each adapter (both v4 and v6) and click Advanced. On the DNS tab, uncheck the box that says "Register this connection's addresses in DNS". Then go in to DNS and delete the unwanted IP addresses.

Comment: You should click the check mark to the left of my answer to mark it as accepted.

Comment: Just FYI longneck- I check the DNS server this morning and its showing the IPs in the records on all DNS servers.

Comment: Look at the windows event log. I think it shows when a client updates an IP address, so you can see who or what did it. If not, enable debug logging. I found directions for windows 2000/2003, but they are probably still applicable to 2008R2. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759581(v=ws.10).aspx